# Not able to parse this using Google Gson in java

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "status":1,
    "list":
        {
            "218888771":
                {
                    "item_id":"218888771",
                    "title":"twitter",
                    "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/oFYGY7z0",
                    "time_updated":"1347094862",
                    "time_added":"1347094862",
                    "state":"0"
                },
            "217345740":
                {
                    "item_id":"217345740",
                    "title":"",
                    "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/dCvNwtrK",
                    "time_updated":"1346790837",
                    "time_added":"1346790700",
                    "state":"0"
                }
        },
    "since":1347094862,
    "complete":1
}
```

I am using Google GSon but not really getting anywhere.

First of all I am confused why I am not able to cast it as a JsonArray. "list" looks like a json Array. But it just doesn't seem to work. I don't mind employing the POJO method of doing it but how do I parse this JSONArray in the first place?

```
  JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement tradeElement = parser.parse(response);
    JsonObject trade = tradeElement.getAsJsonObject();
    json.get("list").getAsJsonObject().get("url")
```

That gave me null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {
   "complete":1,
   "list":{
      "217345740":{
         "item_id":"217345740",
         "state":"0",
         "time_added":"1346790700",
         "time_updated":"1346790837",
         "title":"",
         "url":"http://t.co/dCvNwtrK"
      },
      "218888771":{
         "item_id":"218888771",
         "state":"0",
         "time_added":"1347094862",
         "time_updated":"1347094862",
         "title":"twitter",
         "url":"http://t.co/oFYGY7z0"
      }
   },
   "since":1347094862,
   "status":1
}
```

As you can see when this is well formated `list` is an object having two properties `217345740` and `218888771`. An array is enclosed with brackets `[]`. This is why you're not able to cast it as an array.

Your best choice would be to use correctly gson and its ability to parse json into POJOs.
This is completely untested (I don't knwo Gson that much and I'm not on my development machine), but you will see the idea.

```
public class Item {
    long item_id;
    int state;
    @SerializedName("time_added")
    Date timeAdded;
    @SerializedName("time_updated")
    Date timeUpdated;
    String title;
    String url;

    // getter & setters
}

public class Trade {
    int complete;
    Date since;
    int status;
    Map<Long, Item> list;

    // getter & setters
}

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "";

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
            public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                return new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong()); 
            } 
        });
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        Trade trade = gson.fromJson(json, Trade.class);
        Map<Long, Item> items = trade.getList();
        System.out.println(items.get(217345740L).getUrl()); // should print http://t.co/dCvNwtrK
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do I parse it then?

Answer (score 0):

A JSON Array would be as follows:

```
[
    {
        "item_id":"218888771",
        "title":"twitter",
        "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/oFYGY7z0",
        "time_updated":"1347094862",
        "time_added":"1347094862",
        "state":"0"
    },
    {
        "item_id":"218888771",
        "title":"twitter",
        "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/oFYGY7z0",
        "time_updated":"1347094862",
        "time_added":"1347094862",
        "state":"0"
    },
]
```

The above one is a JSONArray of maps. Since your data is a map of maps, you should browse through the maps with appropriate keys and get to the inner most map that has the "url" key.